# representation of 6 byte MACID

Tags: c++, tcp, network-programming

I am working on Client Server application where I need to send 6 byte mac id (FFF000 - FFF1FF) to the server from the client.
I wanted to know the how best to represent in c++.

I thought of declaring it as unsigned long and then covert it in 6 bytes and send it to the server.

Is this correct do this.
Any Other alternative please suggest.

Comment: Why would it have to be "converted to hexadecimal" to send to the server? Hexadecimal, decimal, octal, base-64, etc. are just different "views" (representations with different symbols) of the same data.

Comment: Sorry it should 6 bytes instead of hexadecimal

Comment: Just use a 64-bit variable (an unsigned long is not necessarily it -- perhaps "long long" or "int64_t"? See [size of int, long, etc](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/589575/c-size-of-int-long-etc)) and only send/use the low-6 bytes?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think I'd use an integral type for this, since we would never treat the value as a number. I would represent it as a sequence of 6 bytes. Some possibilities are:

```
unsigned char macid[6];
typedef unsigned char macid[6];
struct macid {
    unsigned char data[6];
};
```

But in the end, I'd probably opt for:

```
std::tr1::array<unsigned char, 6> macid;
send(serverFd, &macid[0], macid.size());
```

Comment: `std::tr1::array<>` is cool for a short-term solution (or even internal implementation for `macid` class).  If, however, there are named operations to perform on `macid` values, I would definitely opt for the class solution.